# Fetch similar values from an Array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an `array`

```
sample_array = [10001567, 10001789, 2347800, 10001534, 64786592, 00000355]
output_array = [10001567, 10001789, 10001534]
```

I need to fetch all the `elements` into a new `array` where the first 5 digits must be same in a given `array`. How to do this in `ruby`.

Comment: Is it always the first 5 digits you need to match on?

Comment: Is `00000355` an octal value or are you assuming that the numbers are left-padded with zeros?

Comment: @MarkMeyer yes, it is always first 5 digits i need to match, no matter how big the array is I only need elements that have same first 5 digits

Comment: @muistooshort I just gave a random value, mostly all values start with 1-9

Answer (score 1):

```
sample_array = [10001567, 10001789, 2347800, 10001534, 64786592]
patterns = sample_array.group_by { |el| el.to_s.chars.first(5).join.to_i }
=> {10001=>[10001567, 10001789, 10001534], 23478=>[2347800], 64786=>[64786592]}
```

UPDATE
Selecting the pattern *for this specific case*

```
patterns.select{|_,v| v.size > 1}.values.flatten
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked but my output must have an array of only matched elements. FYI, the first 5 elements can be any pattern like 10001,11111,67676,34567,99999.

Comment: What if you'll get more then one pattern of first 5 digits in the array? My answer is more general. You can select the hash values with size > 1.
As long as the elements of the sample array are integers the patter does not really matter.. you have to take 5 digits.